# Ruby script works fine on command line, but fails in Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, hudson, watir

BLUF: Ruby script works fine on command line, but fails in Jenkins.

Env info:

```
Ubuntu 16.04
Watir 6.1.0
Jenkins 2.4
Rubygems 2.6.10

*** LOCAL GEMS **
bigdecimal (default: 1.2.8)
childprocess (0.6.2)
colorize (0.8.1)
dbi (0.4.5)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
ffi (1.9.17)
headless (2.3.1)
io-console (default: 0.4.5)
json (default: 1.8.3)
mail (2.6.4)
mime-types (3.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
minitest (5.10.1, 5.8.4)
mysql2 (0.4.5)
net-ssh (4.1.0)
net-ssh-gateway (2.0.0)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nokogiri (1.7.0.1)
power_assert (1.0.1, 0.2.7)
psych (default: 2.0.17)
rake (12.0.0, 10.5.0)
rdoc (5.1.0, default: 4.2.1)
rubygems-update (2.6.10, 2.6.8)
rubyzip (1.2.1)
selenium-webdriver (3.2.2)
test-unit (3.2.3, 3.1.7)
watir (6.2.0, 6.1.0)
websocket (1.2.4)
```

I have a ruby script I'm running using watir.  It works fine when I run it on the command line, but fails when I run it via a job/build in Jenkins. It always fails because setting the browser doesn't work.  Here is the following error:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /ebs/jenkins/jobs/test watir/workspace
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson6395492977367774608.sh
+ ruby /opt/mysite/ci/regression.rb someSiteName dev false true
Running headless.
Running browser.
/opt/mysite/ci/regression.rb:166:in `<main>': undefined method `close' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  clone
Net::ReadTimeout. /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rbuf_fill'
<br />/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:136:in `readuntil'
<br />/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:146:in `readline'
<br />/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:40:in `read_status_line'
<br />/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:29:in `read_new'
<br />/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1437:in `block in transport_request'
<br />/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1434:in `catch'
<br />/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1434:in `transport_request'
<br />/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1407:in `request'
<br />/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1400:in `block in request'
<br />/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
<br />/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1398:in `request'
<br />/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.2.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:124:in `response_for'
<br />/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.2.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:78:in `request'
<br />/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.2.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:61:in `call'
<br />/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.2.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:671:in `raw_execute'
<br />/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.2.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:110:in `create_session'
<br />/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.2.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:71:in `initialize'
<br />/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.2.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:42:in `initialize'
<br />/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.2.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:61:in `new'
<br />/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.2.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:61:in `for'
<br />/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.2.2/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:87:in `for'
<br />/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/watir-6.2.0/lib/watir/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
<br />/opt/mysite/ci/regression.rb:50:in `new'
<br />/opt/mysite/ci/regression.rb:50:in `<main>'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I double checked versions from the module I'm using that were installed from  'apt'.  I've also double checked the version for each install gem.  I hard coded the variables passed along the command line to the script (as opposed to used a parameterized build).  Here is the code from the script being executed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'watir'
require 'headless'
argSite        = ARGV[0]
argEnvironment = ARGV[1]
argSendEmail   = ARGV[2]
argHeadless    = ARGV[3]
begin
    if argHeadless.to_s == 'true'
        puts "Running headless."
        headless = Headless.new
        headless.start
    end

    puts "Running browser."
# vvv reason tests fail
    browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
    browser.window.resize_to(1200, 1000)
    browser.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 15

...tests go here...

rescue => e
    puts ("#{e}. "+ e.backtrace.join("\n<br />"))
ensure
# vvv script fails here
    browser.close
    if argHeadless.to_s == 'true'
        headless.destroy
    end
end
```

Comment: Seems like `browser` is not initialized. Have you installed `watir-webdriver` to launch Chrome on the machine where Jenkins runs?

Comment: @Uzbekjon i added the requires.  fwiw/fyi, watir 6 only requires "require 'watir'" to be called, no longer requires "*-webdriver".  also chrome is selected by default.  note: chromedriver is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Chrome cannot run as root.  Jenkins is running as root.  When it runs a build, the build is run as root.  In used the following command to change which user the script ran as.

```
su -c 'ruby /opt/mysite/ci/regression.rb someSiteName dev false true' jenkins
```